# While reading csv file, some fields are read along with commas. How can I avoid that?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, csv, odbc

While reading CSV data using C#, some field values are read along with the comma to seperate values. Like if I provide values like 7,8,18 instead of reading value `8` what I am getting is `8,`.

This is how I am reading data

```
OdbcDataReader.GetValue(fieldNumber)
```

Here is my connection string

```
"Driver={Microsoft Text Driver (*.txt, *.csv)};dbg=;"
```

The problem here is its working in dev servers and not in higher environments. Suspected the file encoding. But tried editing the file in same editors. Still same result.

Any ideas or suggestions? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have an example csv file that you could share that renders this bad value? Are the numbers enclosed in quotes or just bare? Could be a localization issue - some regions use a comma instead of a period for the decimal point. Have you tried looking on nuget for a CSV parser instead of using Odbc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wonder if the `CurrentCulture` is different on the dev server than it is on the production server.  You could try temporarily changing to `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture`

```cs
var currentCulture = System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture;
System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;

OdbcDataReader.GetValue(fieldNumber)

System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = currentCulture;
```